# Understanding NIPALS algorithm for PLS

Tags: data-mining, algorithms, partial-least-squares

I've found a [nice presentation](http://vision.cse.psu.edu/seminars/talks/PLSpresentation.pdf) describing PLS1 and PLS2 algorithms (pages 16-19). It's pretty clear but there is a thing confusing me.

**For PLS1.** Let's look at [the algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76NMx.png). The first steps are

- $w = X'y$ (which maximizes $\operatorname{cov}(Xw,y)$)
- $w = w / ||w||$
- $t = Xw$
- $p = X't / t't$

On the one hand one can say $T=XW$ and $WW'=I$, but on the other hand $T=XP$ and $PP'=I$ (because we are searching for a decomposition $X=TP'$ where $PP'=I$, see page 14).

So, my question is, aren't $P$ and $W$ the same matrix? And if so, why does the algorithm need to calculate $p$ as $X't / t't$?

Why not do it this way:

- $p = X'y$
- $p = p / ||p||$
- $t = Xp$

**UPDATE**
After reading provided comments, answers, and links (thanks to @amoeba and @theGD), I get that a strict answer to my question is "No, they are not.". I **almost** understood why. Actually, I lost my hope to fully understand NIPALS algorthm principle. So, I decided to ask it in a differernt way: What is mathematicial task PLS NIPALS tries to solve?

For example, there is NIPALS for PCA as well. And I don't understand it fully too. But I know that it's just a computational method for solving a mathimaticial task (for one iteration):
$$
{\mathbf  {t}}^{T}{\mathbf  {t}} = {\mathbf  {w}}^{T}{\mathbf  {X}}^{T}{\mathbf  {Xw}} \rightarrow \max, \textrm{ given that } \Vert {\mathbf  {w}}\Vert =1
$$
So, what is analogous mathematical task for PLS?

Comment: No, they are not the same. You can easily verify it using your own favourite programming language: generate random $X$ and $y$ (they can be very small), then carry out first steps of this algorithm: compute vector $w$, then vector $t$, then vector $p$. You will see that $w\ne p$.

Comment: The procedure $t = X^{\prime}t/t^{\prime}t$ is to get orthogonal $t$ values, the scores for $X$.

Answer (score 2):

The 14th page is not about PLS, it is about PCA since it refers to decomposition of $X$ alone by carrying out singular value decomposition which is an efficient way to obtain eigenvalues($D$) and eigenvectors($V$) of $\operatorname{cov}(X)$). So in PCA case, the orthogonality of $P$ is correct.

In PLS, however, the only property of $X$ loadings is each vector in $P$ matrix has unit length ($||p_i||$ = 1) whereas $W$ is orthogonal. In fact, the addition of $W$ is to ensure the orthagonality of $X$ scores($T$) and it is one of the main differences between PLS NIPALS and PCA NIPALS. Thus, as said in comments, $P$ and $W$ are not the same matrices.

As a small note I prefer SIMPLS algorithm which is faster and it provides a single vector for regression and makes interpretation a lot easier unlike NIPALS with multiple vectors each corresponding to deflated $X$ which is, in my opinion, quite counter-intuitive and hard to interpret.

The properties of PLS factors obtained by NIPALS algorithm can be found in this article:
[Geladi, Paul, and Bruce R. Kowalski. "Partial least-squares regression: a tutorial." Analytica chimica acta 185 (1986): 1-17.](http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/faculty/reilly/ece712/tutorial%20on%20PLS%20and%20PCA.pdf)

Comment: Direct PDF link: http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/faculty/reilly/ece712/tutorial%20on%20PLS%20and%20PCA.pdf (+1)